# Rewrite rules for custom posts types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

So I created a new post type 'quote'.
Basically I want to change all quotes URLs to domain.com/quotes/ID since as it as right now (`/?quote={xxx}`) could get pretty long, and since this post type is user-input-based, I don't want to take any risks.

So I tried looking for answers... I found a really good tutorial that seemed to partially work. The urls did change, but I ever since I get a `404 page not found` error.
Then, I tried looking for solutions. I tried some like adding `flush_rewrite_rules()`, opening the permalinks page in wordpress admin and press "save", changed my code and changed the slug in the `rewrite` attribute of the post type. As you can guess, nothing worked.

```
function my_custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
              // too long
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our quotes and quotes specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'supports'      => array( 'editor', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite'   => false,
        'query_var'     => true,
    );

    register_post_type( 'quote', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();  //one of the solutions I found

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $projects_structure = '/quotes/%post_id%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%quote%", '([^/]+)', "quote=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('quote', $projects_structure, false);

    add_filter('post_type_link', 'quote_permalink', 10, 3); //translate the structure variables.
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type' );
```

In short, I do get forwarded to `/quotes/ID/`, but the page results in a 404 error.
I did try to look up answers but nothing really worked for me.
Hopefully someone could pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this article may help you.

http://vocecommunications.com/blog/2010/11/adding-rewrite-rules-for-custom-post-types/

I think what you're missing is in the third section, where she's making a redirect rule (I think your site isn't redirecting correctly because it's missing a rule to do so...)